# Android Studio 3.4 waiting for application to come online

Tags: android-studio

Since upgrading to AS 3.4 I can no longer debug any of my apps. I have made no changes to any of the projects, I just upgraded AS. Now all I get is "Waiting for application to come online".

When I click on Run->Attach Debugger To Android Process, there are no processes to attach.

The apps load and run, but I cannot debug them.

Is there anything I can do to get the debugger working?

(I have tried clean, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart, make project and gradlew clean).

Answer (score 1):

I found the same trobles in Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1) when created a new project with no activity. After the project creation I created a main activity and add a launcher intent-filter and tried to debug it. And found "Waiting for application to come online". I found that "Launch" argument in "Lunch Option" for my "Run Configuration" is "Nothing". Problem solved by changing it to "Default Activity"
To change run configuration option select Run->Edit Configurations, or "Modify Run Configuration" in Run or Debug panel.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I tried: Update Android studio to 3.5, restart cache, delete cache folders, killing adb server and restart it... but nothing works.

I solved executing the next commands on ADB terminal:

On windows, you have to change to platform-tools folder path in order to excecute ADB commands, something like this:

```
cd C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

Then, compile your app on debug mode. (I think shift + F9 on Windows), when you started to see **"Waiting for application to come online"** message, execute the next adb command:

`adb shell am start -n com.example.yourPackage/com.example.yourPackage.MainActivity -D`

Just change **com.example.yourPackage** and make sure **MainActivity** its your Luncher Activity inside your Manifest File.

Comment: OK , tried it .. the app seems to run in debug mode , however , none of the breakpoints work ..